# How to add value to a list in class that have a string array?

Tags: arrays, list, class

I am creating a tournument app that will have group stage and knockouts. I'm using a class with a list to create different groups so i can save them to an xml file later.

this is how my list and class looks like (*xmlHandlerScript*).

```
public void AddGroup(int group,string[] team)
{

    groupDB.list.Add(new Groups { groupIndex = group, team = team });   
}

public GroupDatabse groupDB;

[System.Serializable]
public class Groups
{
    public int groupIndex;
    public string[] team;          
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GroupDatabse
{
    public List<Groups> list = new List<Groups>();
}
```

this is how i add value to list variables.

```
 groups = new string[totalTeamsPerGroup];
 int  j = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < totalGroups; i++)
  {
        for (int x = 0; x < totalTeamsPerGroup; x++)
        {

            groups[x] = teams[j];                   
            j++;
        }
            xmlHandlerScript.AddGroup(i, groups);

   }
```

My problem is when i have more then 1 "*totalGroups*" and add the array "*groups*" to the List, the *string[] team* gets replaced with the last *teams[]* in both my arrays

like this:

[Teams in Tournument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOxHu.png)
[Groups after i added them to list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaFZ5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you need to re-initialize the groups list for each team iteration. I've used a List instead of an array since Lists in c# are much simpler to manage.

```
 int  j = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < totalGroups; i++)
  {
       var groups = new List<string>();
        for (int x = 0; x < totalTeamsPerGroup; x++)
        {

            groups.Add(teams[j]);                   
            j++;
        }
            xmlHandlerScript.AddGroup(i, groups);

   }
```